# Remote Debugger is not attaching to Azure App Service with VS2019

Tags: azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-2019, azure-appservice

I know many similar questions have been asked here. And usually the answer is just where to find the option/menu in VS. But I need to know why my VS cannot attach to my App Service.

Everything I can see and MS and other on the net ever mentioned is set up. I can debug other App Services. The address is ping-able.

Deployment: Azure Pipeline(.yml; Publish from VS is impossible)
Error message (by "Attach to Process..." and in Cloud Explorer): [ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Grka.png) (definitely wrong)

Thank you very much in advance!

So no idea anyone!?! MS neither :(. We just have to accept that they give a crap about their systems and tools working. Goodbye MS...

Comment: VS 2019 , attempting to debug was 32-bit and port 4025 was not open on the network.

The ports listed for the remote debugger are for 64-bit processes when running the 64-bit debugger. For debugging 32-bit (using the 64-bit debugger) you need the next port up (which is why each version of VS uses ports 2 up from the last version).

Comment: The debugger is included in the standard install at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe

Comment: Downloaded it now from the following page:

[Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugger](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202019)

Comment: @ HarshithaVeeramalla-MT: I am not running the debugger program. It runs automatically in the background of the App Service (MS claims, although VS claims the opposite). So this (just like installing it locally) doesn't help at all, like in all the other posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out (hidden blockers in Azure).
But sadly, again no comment was even close to be helpful or really about the topic...

Comment: What were the hidden blockers?

Answer (score 2):

- I got the same issue and Resolved by following the below steps
- Make sure Remote Debugging is enabled  in Azure Portal.
  Azure Portal =>Your App Service =>Configuration => Select General settings.

[image]

**Attach to Process**

Visual studio 2019=> Go to Debug tab => Click on Attach process => In Dialog there is Connection Target paste your site url without htttp like([myappservice.azurewebsites.net](http://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/))
=> Hit the Refresh button => Again dialog appears add your app service credentials username and password=> A list of process will be shown to you just click on the msvsmon.exe process => Now check debugger is attached and now you can debug .

[image]

**To get credentials**

There are two ways to get username and password

- Download publish profile and open in notepad++ there you can see the username and password.

```cs
    <publishData>  
    <publishProfile profileName="myappservice - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy"  
    publishUrl="[myappservice.azurewebsites.net](http://myappservice.azurewebsites.net/):443"  
    userName="{USERNAME}" userPWD="{PASSWORD}" ...>  
    <databases />  
    </publishProfile>  
    <publishProfile profileName="myappservice - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" ...>  
    <databases />  
    </publishProfile>  
    </publishData>
```

- You can also get this username and password from azure portal
  Go to azure portal  =>Open your app service =>Deployment center  => click on FTPS Credentials,there is the username and password .

### Update

[image]

Comment: Like I said, this is all set correctly already and I can connect to other App Services. Even those with Remote Debugging turned off, ask for the credentials (and fail afterwards). My app does not even do that!

Comment: Btw. we used .NET core 2.1, the public address ("azapp-...") ist blocked by Frontdoor on purpose, the internal address works in the browser.

Comment: .Net Core 2.1 release has reached end of life, it is no longer supported. Please refer [.NET Core 2.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.1) for more details.

Comment: Does that mean, that they secretly disabled the Remote Debugger features of Azure for those Frameworks and not add any error message for that??? In this case I would demand help or money back from MS...

Comment: Please have a look at [.NET Core Support Policy](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core)